# Ember js form retains old values

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I tried other answers here on SO but none of them helped.

```
app/routes/card/new.js

actions: {
  save(title, description) {
    const newCard = this.get('store').createRecord('card', { title, description } );
    newCard.save().then((card) => {
      this.transitionTo('card.card', card);
    });
  }
}
```

For the view, I've:

```
app/templates/card/new.hbs

<form>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="card-title">Card Title</label>
    {{input type="text" value=title class="form-control" id="card-title" placeholder="Enter the title of the card"}}
    <small class="text-muted">Give your card a nice title</small>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="card-description">Card Description</label>
    {{textarea value=description class="form-control" id="card-description" rows="3"}}
    <small class="text-muted">Describe your card</small>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Save or Cancel your card">
    <button {{action 'save' title description}} class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
    <button {{action 'cancel'}} class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I create a card, it works fine but when I again try creating a new car, the form retains the old values which disappears on refresh.

Comment: Maybe the browser causes saving fields

Comment: i can see the old data (properties) in the ember console `title:asd description :asd`. so, my browser is not caching it.

Comment: Your browser saves fields. You can see them because you don't bind fields to your model.

Comment: And not related to this issue you should put `save` action in `card/new` controller.

Comment: then how can i make the input fields blank again after submission? i tried `this.set(title, '')` inside the save promise but it didn't clear the field.

Comment: can't i use the `save` action in the `card/new.js` route?

Comment: No. in new route `model` hook return new record

Comment: Actions should be in controllers

Comment: thank you for your answer. just a confusion. aren't controllers going away (http://emberigniter.com/should-we-use-controllers-ember-2.0/) ?

Comment: They are not disappeared totally. Best practice is that you encapsulate these form in a `component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/routes/card/new.js

```
model(){
  return this.get('store').createRecord('card');
}
```

app/controllers/card/new.js

```
actions: {
  save(){
   this.get('model').save().then((card) => {
      this.transitionTo('card.card', card);
    });
}
}
```

app/templates/card/new.hbs

```
<form>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="card-title">Card Title</label>
    {{input type="text" value=model.title class="form-control" id="card-title" placeholder="Enter the title of the card"}}
    <small class="text-muted">Give your card a nice title</small>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="card-description">Card Description</label>
    {{textarea value=model.description class="form-control" id="card-description" rows="3"}}
    <small class="text-muted">Describe your card</small>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Save or Cancel your card">
    <button {{action 'save'}} class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
    <button {{action 'cancel'}} class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i'm using components. but there i can't do `this.get('model').save().then((card) => {...})` as `this.get('model')` is undefined. any idea why?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Do you use `model` hook in your route as I wrote in answer?

Comment: inside `app/routes/card/new.js`, i've this: `model(){
    return this.get('store').createRecord('card');
  }`

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Do you put `form` in a component? If yes, so how do you pass model to component?

Comment: hey, it worked. i passed the `model` to the component. thanks.

Comment: one more thing. how can i use `this.transitionTo('card.card', card)` after the new card is saved?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh For example in component : `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('route:card.index').transitionTo('card.card', card);`

Comment: one last thing. i've access to `this.get('title')` from inside the component. but i need it while creating the new record like `this.get('store').createRecord('card', { title, description } )` in `app/routes/card/new.js` but `this.get('title')` is not present there. so, the response to the backend is going as null!

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh `this.get('model.title');`

Comment: if i do something like `this.get('store').createRecord('card', { title, description })` where `title` is `this.get('model.title')` then it's `undefined`. do i need to do `this.get('store').createRecord('card', { title, description })` inside `/app/components/forms/new-card-form.js`?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh I don't know how you pass model and how you structure your app. For your question, NO. You should create that model in route. How you pass model to component?

Comment: in `app/templates/card/new.hbs`, i do something like `{{forms/new-card-form model=model}}` where `new-card-form` is the name of the component.

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh So you should have `model` in that component. Can you twiddle your code?

Comment: i've updated the code here: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client. can you please view there?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Why you do this in https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client/blob/master/app/routes/card/new.js#L5?? It's not meaningful

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Please take a look at https://ember-twiddle.com/153482bcced1b5d63b6df058eec262a6